# Can anyone translate speech from a recording?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I have a short audio sample in Latin, but cannot make it out.

Can anyone provide a transcription and translation of what it says?

[Here's a link to the audio file on Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JFmkDe6fX_dDZ3UTRtUnY0R3M/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: This is not a great recording, it almost sounds as if this person is speaking underwater to me.

Comment: I know it's not the best but it was sent to me and I would really like to know what it means.

Comment: I tried cleaning it up here is the link to the slightly cleaner version. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JFmkDe6fX_cFlwcXFFVDBDVWM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I can't quite make it out, but for others who are attempting, the first words sounds to me like _militaribus_.

Comment: Interesting question! A request: Please do not remove the file so that the link remains accessible for future readers. If you think long term storage of the file is hard, let us know and we'll try to figure something out.

Answer (score 3):

It seems pretty clear to me that the recording says:

> **militaribus viris incredulitate**

This exact word sequence does not occur in any corpus I can find, and is meaningless outside of its grammatical context. Here's a sample sentence I came up with that could use that word sequence:

> Unus ex **militaribus viris incredulitate** demersus fugit.
>
> <sup>One of the **soldiers**, overwhelemed **with disbelief**, fled.</sup>

Comment: I'm sorry, but where does _viris_ fit into that example sentence?

Comment: @SamK A *militaris vir* is a soldier or, if you prefer, a "military man." It's a combination [noted in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmilitaris)

Comment: Ah, thank you for that clarification. I was not aware of that, but the more you know I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like it's saying *militaribus avidis incredulitate*. A quick Google search doesn't show me any hits for anything important, so maybe I'm mishearing, or maybe it's nothing really at all.

It's a little ambiguous without context, but it means something like "with soldiers eager with disbelief." The last word is post-classical, so if it does come from something, it's not from ancient Rome.

Comment: Edit: on second listening, I do hear the *viris*. Not the best recording.